Subparsing or not subparsing using argparse in Python
I'm a Python beginner who's new to the argparse module so please bear with me. I wanted to use argparse to parse a simple program I'm making, but I think my understanding of it is faulty. Basically, I wanted make a program where I can manage and edit files.
managing files:
[COMMAND] [FILE]
which would allow a basic file management command, like this:
C .\file.txt # create a file
editing files:
[PRINT] [content of a working file]
or
[EDIT] [content of a working file]
like this:
E -usr "mark b" -pwd "password123" # edit the username stored  using -usr and password using -pwd
P -usr # print the username

Since printing and editing uses a lot of the same options like username, posts, biography, etc., I thought I should put them in separate subparsers. I put my file management commands into the main parser, which requires it to precede the P and E commands which I do not want, so I tried putting them into a subparser also, but still getting errors.
F -C file
usage: scratch.py [-h] {-F,-P,-E} ...
scratch.py: error: argument {-F,-P,-E}: invalid choice: 'file' (choose from '-F', '-P', '-E')

P -usr
usage: scratch.py [-h] {-P,-E} ...
scratch.py: error: unrecognized arguments: -P -usr

This is my code:
def parser(tokens):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()
    # file management commands
    f_parser = subparsers.add_parser('-F', description='.dsu file management')
    f_parser.add_argument('-C', help='Create new .dsu file', type=Path)
    f_parser.add_argument('-D', help='Delete .dsu file', type=Path)
    f_parser.add_argument('-R', help='Read .dsu file', type=Path)
    f_parser.add_argument('-Q', help='Quit PyJournal', type=Path)
    f_parser.add_argument('-O', help='Load a .dsu file', type=Path)
    # print parser
    p_parser = subparsers.add_parser('-P', help='Print Profile content')
    p_parser.add_argument('-usr', action='store_true', dest='username')
    p_parser.add_argument('-pwd', action='store_true', dest='password')
    p_parser.add_argument('-bio', action='store_true', dest='bio')
    p_parser.add_argument('-posts', action='store_true', dest='posts')
    p_parser.add_argument('-post', action='store', dest='post', type=int)
    p_parser.add_argument('-all', action='store_true', dest='all')
    # edit parser
    e_parser = subparsers.add_parser('-E', help='Edit Profile content')
    e_parser.add_argument('-addpost', action='store', dest='new_post')
    e_parser.add_argument('-delpost', action='store', dest='del_post', type=int)
    e_parser.add_argument('-usr', action='store', dest='username')
    e_parser.add_argument('-pwd', action='store', dest='password')
    e_parser.add_argument('-bio', action='store', dest='bio')
    args = parser.parse_args(tokens)
    if args.all:
        args.username = True
        args.password = True
        args.bio = True
        args.posts = True

    return vars(args)

Ideally I don't want to put an additional command in front of the file management commands, while being able to parse my print and edit commands. Should I be using subparsing at all? I hope this make sense.

Subparsers are generally used to implement the subcommand pattern in a manner similar to CLI utilities such as git and docker (e.g. git commit, git checkout, docker info, docker run are some examples of using subcommands of a top level command).
Note that subcommands generally are whole words that don't start with the -, as - are typically reserved for flags that would modify the function of the utility (e.g. git -C /path/to/repo/.git log -p will set the -C flag on git to specify which repository to open, and -p specifies to log to include the diff in the log output).
In the design of argparse, norms in existing CLI utilities heavily influence how parsing is typically designed to work, so argparser will simply ignore subparsers that have a command that starts with a - as it's assumed incoming tokens that start with - are simply flags and not subcommands.  In fact, this issue was reported and was closed as an invalid/won't fix by CPython.
If you want to use subcommand pattern, just remove the - character before each command, e.g.:
f_parser = subparsers.add_parser('F', description='.dsu file management')

With that your commands like F -C file will just work - your intended use case didn't include the - before F so it didn't even make sense for you in the first place to include that in your parser specification.
